# How to make a line in svg vibrate (oscillation move)

Tags: html, css, svg

Let's suppose we do have  a simple svg file like this:

```html
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <line x1="10" y1="50" x2="250" y2="50"  stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="270" cy="50" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Which gives us a line with and circle, I want to vibrate the line the circle (an oscillation, I'm not sure if that word is correct, like if winds make it move), so it gives the graph a life.

How can I do a such animation please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point you may need to

1. transform the line in a path with a line written as a cubic bezier
2. calculate 2 other paths as the position and shape of the bented curve up and down
3. In this case I'm adding a simple SMIL animation betwin the 3 variants of the curve.

4.the circle's center is corresponding to the ending point of the curve. Alternatively you may want to use a marker instead.

You can elaborare starting from this idea.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 -50 300 200" width="300"> 
  <path stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"  d="M10,50C100,50 200,50 250,50">
    <animate 
       attributeName="d"
       values="M10,50C100,50 200,50 250,50;
               M10,50C100,50 200,50 248,80;
               M10,50C100,50 200,50 250,50;
               M10,50C100,50 200,50 248,20; 
               M10,50C100,50 200,50 250,50;"
       dur="5s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </path>
   
  <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" >
    <animate 
       attributeName="cx"
       values="250;248;250;248;250"
       dur="5s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"/>
     <animate 
       attributeName="cy"
       values="50;80;50;20;50"
       dur="5s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

the OP is commenting:

> I want to make an image inside the circle (instead of the red fill)

In this case I'm putting the image inside a symbol and I'm clipping the image with a circle of the same radius.

I'm using the symbol with `use` and I'm animating the use element the way I've animated the circle in the previous example:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 -50 300 200" width="300"> 
<clipPath id="cp">
<circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</clipPath>

  <path stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"  d="M10,50C100,50 200,50 250,50">
    <animate 
       attributeName="d"
       values="M10,50C100,50 200,50 250,50;
               M10,50C100,50 200,50 248,80;
               M10,50C100,50 200,50 250,50;
               M10,50C100,50 200,50 248,20; 
               M10,50C100,50 200,50 250,50;"
       dur="5s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </path>
<symbol id="s">   
<image  xlink:href ="https://assets.codepen.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" width="40" height="40"  clip-path="url(#cp)"/>
</symbol>

<use xlink:href="#s" x="230" y="30">
    <animate 
       attributeName="x"
       values="230;228;230;228;230"
       dur="5s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"/>
     <animate 
       attributeName="y"
       values="30;60;30;0;30"
       dur="5s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to make the same animation for an image ?!

Comment: I don't understand your question. An image instead of what? Anyway please ask this as a different question. and give more details. I would like to help.

Comment: Thanks for being helpful, I really don't see the ambiguity in my question, anyway I'll sum up my goal, in that schema (that you've made) I want to make an image inside the circle (instead of the red fill), i managed to do it statically without animation and I'm asking if i can manage to do so :/ should i make a new question for this ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please take a look

Comment: You gave me everything, I don't know how to thank you...